# Printing list to Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to print the `reviews` array as a list to my label so it doesn't just come out in a single line.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo

movies = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Python Programs/ml-latest-small/movies.csv')
ratings = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Python Programs/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')

ratings.drop(['timestamp'], axis=1, inplace= True)  

class App(Frame):

    def replace_name(x):
      return movies[movies['movieId']==x].title.values[0]

    ratings.movieId = ratings.movieId.map(replace_name)

    M = ratings.pivot_table(index=['userId'], columns=['movieId'], values='rating')

    def pearsons(s1, s2):
        s1_c = s1 - s1.mean()
        s2_c = s2 - s2.mean()
        return np.sum(s1_c * s2_c) / np.sqrt(np.sum(s1_c ** 2) * np.sum(s2_c ** 2))

    def get_recs(self):
        movie_name = self.mn.get()
        num_recs_str = self.nr.get()
        num_recs = int(num_recs_str)
        reviews = []
        for title in App.M.columns:
            if title==movie_name:
                continue
            cor = App.pearsons(App.M[movie_name], App.M[title])
            if np.isnan(cor):
                continue
            else:
                reviews.append((title, cor))

        reviews.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
        for x in reviews:
            self.label3.config(text= "\n" + str(reviews[:num_recs]))
        #self.label3.config(text=reviews[:num_recs])
        return reviews[:num_recs]

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.filename = None
        label1=Label(master, text="Movie: ").grid(row=0)
        label2=Label(master, text="Recommendations: ").grid(row=1)
        self.label3=Label(master, text = "", font = 'Purisa', fg='blue')
        self.label3.grid(row = 3)
        self.mn = Entry(master)
        self.mn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        #self.mn.delete(0, END)
        self.mn.insert(0, "Enter Movie Name")
        self.nr = Entry(master)
        self.nr.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        #self.nr.delete(0, END)
        self.nr.insert(0, "Enter Number of Recommendations")
        button1 = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.get_recs)
        button2 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid(row = 2, padx= 5)
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("Recommender")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an image of the current output

[image]

Comment: Mind making a short reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't modify your code because I don't have the files you opened in your code. However, this is an idea to solve your question:

```
from tkinter import *
things_to_print=['something','one thing','another']
root=Tk()
for i in range(len(things_to_print)):
    exec('Label%d=Label(root,text="%s")\nLabel%d.pack()' % (i,things_to_print[i],i))
root.mainloop()
```

I think you can solve your problem by substituting your `reviews` into my `things_to_print` and maybe some other slight modifications.

Comment: Thank you very much, with a few minor adjustments this worked well. The resulting line of code looked like this:                                            
    `for i in range(num_recs):
            exec('Label%d=Label(root,text="%s")\nLabel%d.grid()' % 
    (i,reviews[i],i))`

Comment: @Keegan I am glad to know it worked well. If you think my answer was helpful, you may choose to accept my answer (just click on the check symbol to the left of this answer).